# What are the estimate-estimate and estimate-project algorithms for quantum overlap?

Tags: quantum-state, fidelity, state-tomography, swap-test

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10639) paper on improvements to the traditional SWAP test to measure quantum state overlap (or fidelity), they mention two methods called estimate-estimate and estimate-project.

I googled about these methods, but can’t find any real references or papers on them. Do they go by other names? If so, where can I find them?

I think the estimate-estimate method involves estimating both quantum states, then computing their inner product classically, but this seems much more inefficient than the SWAP test, whereas the paper says it’s more efficient.

Comment: that notation seems to be introduced in the paper itself. They're explained at around page 3 as far as I can tell. Eg "*The estimate-and-estimate (EE) strategy instead consists in estimating both $|\psi\rangle$ and $|φ\rangle$ separately, then computing the overlap between the estimated states*"

Comment: @glS Oh. I saw that quote, but I don’t see how that can be faster than a SWAP test. It seems like they are suggesting something similar to tomography.

Comment: well, that seems to be the whole point of the paper. On a very cursory look the gist seems to be in the advantages you get from global measurements, which seem to give overall better performances than the swap test. It's a fair question, but then you're not asking what are estimate-estimate and estimate-project algorithms, you're asking why these are more efficient than the swap. I'd probably be even better if you can make the question more specific about what you don't understand about how the paper explains it (given that the paper is otherwise a direct answer to your question)